# Why :last-child selector stop apply when adding a different div

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello I'm trying to understand the `:last-child` selector but it doesn't work as I expected to understand

here is an easy code example

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-50">
    <p> allo </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-50">
    <p> allo </p>
  </div>
  <div> allo </div>
</div>
```

```
.container
  .flex-50:last-child
    color: red
```

If I remove the last useless `div` it's correctly red but with the `div` tag it's not red anymore and even in the last `div` tag it's not red.

So, I guess I don't understand how `:last-child` works I thought it would color the last child named `flex-50` in my controller or at least it would color last element of all my `flex-50` but it doesn't neither.

`:last-child` apply to who ?

Comment: Try `:last-of-type` instead of `:last-child`.

Comment: Already tried and doesn't change anything